# Is it possible to detect touches on camera using sensor in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sensors

Is it possible to detect touches on camera using sensor in objective c? I want to create an app that start detecting heart beat when I put my fingure on camera. so is it possible. It will be really helpfull if is there any refrence or example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API used to detect heart rates, these apps do so in a variety of ways. Some will use the accelerometer to measure when the device shakes with each pulse. Other use the camera lens, with the flash on, then detect when blood moves through the finger by detecting the light levels that can be seen.

Comment: is there any example for camera lens,with the flash on.

Comment: suppose i want to start my method when i put my fingure on flash or camera . how can i detect it?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect tap on camera

For that you need to use custom camera using `AVCaptureSession`

You can find tutorial here

https://dannygtech.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/custom-camera-on-ios-avcapturesession-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-tutorial/

In `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`  you can add Tap Gesture on that event you can call your event you need to perform

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to get heart beat by tapping on camera

but you can get tap area by adding UITapGestureRecognizer on camera view(uiimagepicker)to get where user has tapped and perform action .